# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable/unknown error/no exp

Tags: python, callable

I'm trying to numerically integrate the normal distribution function usng the trapezoidal rul:

```
import math as m
def f(x):
    N(x)
    return x

def N(x):
    x=((2*m.pi)**-(1/2))*m.e(-(1/2)*x**2)
    return x

def trap(a, b, n):
    h = float(b - a) / n
    t = 0.0
    for i in range(1, n):
        t += f(a + i*h)
    t += (f(a)+f(b))/2.0
    return t * h

n=int(raw_input("the value of n is:"))
a=int(raw_input("the value of a is:"))
b=int(raw_input("the value of b is:"))


print(trap(a,b,n))
```

However, when I try to call

```
x=((2*m.pi)**-(1/2))*m.e(-(1/2)*x**2)
```

I get the the following error in *line 15, in N*:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: If `e` is a float, you're trying to call it when you write `e(-(1/2)*x2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.e` is the constant 2.71... It's a float not a callable.  The exponential function is `math.exp`